# Do GDO units have any kind of receive notification?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, stargate-atlantis, stargate-universe

In Stargate SG-1 (as well as its spinoffs "Stargate: Atlantis" and "Stargate Universe"), teams or individuals who travel through a stargate must use a GDO unit to enter their passcode once they open the gate from the other side. This code tells Stargate Command that the person(s) coming through the gate are friendly. If a code is not entered or is rejected, the iris stays shut and anyone entering the gate never re-materializes on the Earth side. Or, as Jack O'Neill puts it, they're like "bugs on a windshield". In the show, teams under fire frequently enter their code, wait a second or two, then jump through the gate.

I've seen the shows, but haven't read the various novels and/or comics out there. Two-way communication is possible through both an incoming and outgoing gate, so logically there is no reason why the SGC computer system wouldn't send a "Iris Open" message back to the GDO unit the code was entered on. I don't recall that sort of thing ever being mentioned or shown, however, and even recall the team entering the gate at least once with a "Well, let's hope the iris is open or it'll be a short ride" kind of comment.

**Does the GDO unit have any kind of "code received" notification, or do SGC teams just enter the code, jump through the gate and hope for the best?**

Comment: This question already has an answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56319/how-do-people-know-the-iris-is-open-in-stargate-sg-1)

Comment: @Revenant - cool, missed that question when i searched for it first. Thanks!